# In QGIS, how to group the days of a year every 15 days?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

In [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org), how to group the days of a year every 15 days? I have a column with date values throughout 2018, I would like to create a new column identifying which group that date is in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose your date value is in **your_date** column.

```
floor(day(age("your_date", '2018-01-01')) / 15)
```

The expression above gives 0 for the first 15 days, 1 from 16th to 30th days, ...

Thee **age** function calculates an interval between the to dates, the **day** function extracts the number of days from the interval, the **floor** function returns the nearest smaller integer value of the division.

[image]